# What is ProductGuides folder within the System Information app?

Tags: macos, mac, imac

I was casually browsing my PC when I checked Energy Star certificate in the about section of my Mac.

I searched this document on Finder, where I found out this document is inside a folder called `ProductGuides`, which itself is inside a folder called `Resources`, which is inside the app folder of `System Information`.

I don't have permission to write on this document. What is this document and folder? Can I delete this?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are talking about `/System/Applications/Utilities/System Information.app/Contents/Resources/ProductGuides`.

This is a folder which is part of the **System Information** application. As the application itself is part of macOS, you can neither write to this folder nor delete it.

Comment: Thank you. And yes I am talking about this. There are some pdf which are not related to my device such as a pdf for macbookpro , imacs etc. I don't own any of these product so I want to delete those PDFs.

Comment: @RandomCookieStealer it‘s most likely not worth the effort. These files aren‘t that big, and any macOS update may reinstall them anyway.